# Java minecraft server cannot run/listen on IPv4 at a linux virtual server machine

Tags: java, linux, server, minecraft

There is a Linux centOS 6 system installed on a parallels virtual machine as a vServer with one public IPv4 address XX.XXX.XXX.XX

I try to run a Java Minecraft Server on it but that does not work. I can't connect to the server with my IPv4 address at the specified port.

If I run the command:

```
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft-server.jar nogui 

-->

[14:55:47] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting minecraft server version 1.12.2
[14:55:47] [Server thread/INFO]: Loading properties
[14:55:47] [Server thread/INFO]: Default game type: CREATIVE
[14:55:47] [Server thread/INFO]: Generating keypair
[14:55:48] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting Minecraft server on XX.XXX.XXX.XX:12345
[14:55:48] [Server thread/INFO]: Using epoll channel type
Nov 01, 2018 2:55:48 PM  io.netty.util.internal.MacAddressUtil defaultMachineId 
WARNING: Failed to find a usable hardware address from the network interfaces; using random bytes: 8b:07:0a:a8:aa:46:68:dd
```

When I check the connections there is only a process listening at IPv6 loopback address:

```
lsof -i

COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE  SIZE/OFF  NODE NAME
java      9962  minecraftServer  21u  IPv6 1030838584  0t0  TCP sXXXXXXX.onlinehome-server.info:italk (LISTEN)

netstat -lptu

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             Stat
tcp        0      0 s18608488.onlinehome-:italk *:*                         LISTEN   9962/java

netstat -tulpn

Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:82.165.154.60:12345  :::*                        LISTEN      9962/java
```

This are all avaible Java connections.

I tried a soulution I found here and elsewhere with

```
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -jar minecraft-server.jar nogui
```

though, this also does not work.
I get stuck and have no Idea anymore, suggestions
on other websites did not helped.

Comment: StackOverflow mainly focuses on programming. Since your question is more about system administration, you might want to try posting it on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

*As [@Harry Cutts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175455/harry-cutts) mentioned you should post this question on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/).*
From the question I conclude that you set the `server-ip` value in the `server.properties` to your *public* IPv4 address and thats the source of your problem.
Leave blank the `server-ip` value if you have only one network interface, because it will automatically uses that *private* IPv4 address, but if you have more than one network interface you should provide the IPv4 address of the prefered device.
IP bindings as I already mentioned before are used if there are multiple network interfaces (e.g. server machines) where you need to specify the *local* IPv4 address of the interface for the server (software) to use and later you need to forward the port to that IPv4 address in your router settings.
*(Private (or local) IPv4 adresses are usually looks like this: `192.168.x.x`. But you can learn more on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network).)*
I hope this will help you to solve the issue.